# Making three difficulty level easy, medium, hard quiz

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, operands

So Basically I have to write a program that asks the user for the difficulty level from the user and print questions and even the limit of questions asked from the user. I am facing an issue that I am not able to print questions like these:

1. What is 21+86?
2. What is 92/2?
3. What is 86-70?.

```py
number_1 = random.randrange(1, 100000)
number_2 = random.randrange(1, 100000)
```

When I use this command I get number like 19899 + 198846. which I don't want. I have no idea what to do.

```py
import random

print ("Welcome Little Brother!")
#This Educational Software will help you with your arithmetic problem and polish your skills.
score = 0
print("Please make a selection from the following:")
print("P: Practice Math.")
print("S: Show Score.")
print("Q: Quit.")

selection = input("What do you want to do:")

if selection == "S" :
    print ("No score found.")
elif selection == "P":
    print("What difficult level do you want:")
    print("E: Easy.")
    print("M: Medium.")
    print("H: Hard.")

level = input("Enter Difficulty Level:")

numberofproblem = int(input("How many problems do you want :"))

max_number = numberofproblem

for question_num in range(1, max_number+1):
    if level == "E" :
        ops = ['+', '-']
    elif level == "M" :
        ops = ['+', '-', '*']
    elif level == "H" :
        ops = ['+', '-', '*','/']
    else:
        print ("Incorrect Menu Key Selected")

    number_1 = random.randrange(1, 100000)
    number_2 = random.randrange(1, 100000)
    operation = random.choice(ops)

    maths = round(eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2)),5)
    print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
    print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)
    answer = float(input("What is your answer: "))
    if answer == maths:
        print("Correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)
```

Comment: If you don't want big number, don't use such a large range in `number_1 = random.randrange(1, 100000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary to choose the difficulty and assign it to a function to run that difficulty quiz

```
from random import choice
def easy():
   CorrectQuestions = 0
   IncorrectQuestions = 0
   #I want 3 easy questions
   easyQuestions = {'Question':'answer','Question':'answer','Question':'answer','Question':'answer'}
   Q1 = choice(easyQuestions)
   Q2 = choice(easyQuestions)
   Q3 = choice(easyQuestions)
   print("Question 1:\n")
   answer = input(Q1)
   if answer == easyQuestions[Q1]:
      print("Correct")
      CorrectAnswers += 1
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
      IncorrectAnswers +=1
   print("Question 2:\n")
   answer2 = input(Q2)
   if answer2 == easyQuestions[Q2]:
      print("Correct")
      CorrectAnswers += 1
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
      IncorrectAnswers += 1
   print("Question 3:\n')
   answer3 = input(Q3)
   if answer3 == easyQuestions[Q3]:
      print("Correct")
      CorrectAnswers += 1
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
      IncorrectAnswers += 1
   results = f"You got {str(CorrectAnswers)} answers correct and {str(IncorrectAnswers)} answers wrong."
def medium():
   #code
def hard():
   #code
diff = {'easy':easy,'medium':medium,'hard':hard}
Difficulty = input("Enter Difficulty:")
for i in diff:
    if(Difficulty == diff[i]:
       diff[i]()
    else:
       continue
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, but I am still a little bit confused as to how do I let the program randomly pick questions and give them to the user. And what code will I add in def easy().

Comment: I made an example that should work in the easy function

Comment: Also for reference on your code, make the selection input ToUpper so that no matter if it is capital or not when inputted it is still equal in the conditional

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help you have given.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) of `randrange()`, the values are generated in the range `[a,b)`.

```
number_1 = random.randrange(1, 100000)
number_2 = random.randrange(1, 100000)
```

This means that in your case a random value between `1` and `100'000` is generated. Try to lower the second number so that any number generated is acceptable. `100` might be a good fit for your example.